# Deploying a VC++ Assembly to Azure

Tags: visual-c++, azure

I have an Azure cloud solution with a single C# Web role. As part of this role I'd like to reference an assembly that was compiled in VC++ 2010.

I've added a reference to the assembly and can run the project locally using the Development Fabric without any problem. When I tried to deploy this to Windows Azure, the role went into the initializing-busy-stopping loop that it goes into when it can't start the role.

I read that the C++ runtime DLLs (msvcp100.dll and msvcr100.dll) aren't included in the Azure OS builds, so I also added these to the solution, set them to 'copy always', and did a test build, checking the .csx folder on disk to make sure that the runtime files ended up in the bin folder. They did (as well as in the project's main folder). So, I redeployed, and am still getting the same problem - initializing-busy-stopping.

I then tried creating a brand new solution with a default C# web role, and didn't change any code - just added the references to the assembly and runtime as above. Still no joy - same problem.

Unfortunately I don't have VC++ on my machine, so am using an assembly someone else compiled - but even still, as it works in the dev fabric I doubt the assembly is corrupt.

Does anyone have any suggestions to get a VC++ 2010 assembly working on Azure?

Thanks,

John

Comment: Also I should note that I checked the WAD diagnostics tables, and there's nothing recorded from any of these.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the C++ source code?  If so you can install VS2010 and VS2008 Express and build the existing VS2010 project to target VS2008 runtimes [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx).

PS is this native or managed C++ (C++/CLI) code?